# Normalise between 0 and 1 ignoring NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

For a list of numbers ranging from `x` to `y` that may contain `NaN`, how can I normalise between 0 and 1, ignoring the `NaN` values (they stay as `NaN`).

Typically I would use `MinMaxScaler` ([ref page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler)) from `sklearn.preprocessing`, but this cannot handle `NaN` and recommends imputing the values based on mean or median etc. it doesn't offer the option to ignore all the `NaN` values.

Comment: Use `np.nanmax` and `np.nanmin` instead of `np.max` and `np.min`, the rest should work fine.

Comment: So, basically : `(a-np.nanmin(a))/(np.nanmax(a) - np.nanmin(a))`.

Comment: pandas also deals gracefully with `NaN`s, so a simple `(a - a.min()) / (a.max() - a.min())` does the job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

consider `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([3, 4, 5, 6, np.nan], 100))
s.hist()
```

[image]

---

***Option 1***
Min Max Scaling

```
new = s.sub(s.min()).div((s.max() - s.min()))
new.hist()
```

[image]

---

**NOT WHAT OP ASKED FOR**
I put these in because I wanted to

***Option 2***
sigmoid

```
sigmoid = lambda x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

new = sigmoid(s.sub(s.mean()))
new.hist()
```

[image]

---

***Option 3***
tanh (hyperbolic tangent)

```
new = np.tanh(s.sub(s.mean())).add(1).div(2)
new.hist()
```

[image]

Comment: -1 The OP clearly indicated that he was interested in the linear scaling by referencing `MinMaxScaler`. Options 2 and 3 are irrelevant for the OP, and confuse the reader more than help them in my opinion.

Comment: @user40314 Kudos for commenting on why you down voted.  I'll use that to improve the answer and make it clearer.

Comment: Whom ever down voted this answer. I'd appreciate an explanation. This has been modified to provide what OP wanted and has been accepted.

Comment: I think the answer is clear and that the other options are useful for other readers that are looking for a wider answer.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a different approach and one that I believe answers the OP correctly, the only difference is this works for a dataframe instead of a list, you can easily put your list in a dataframe as done below. The other options didn't work for me because I needed to store the MinMaxScaler in order to reverse transform after a prediction was made. So instead of passing the entire column to the MinMaxScaler you can filter out NaNs for both the target and the input.

*Solution Example*

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

d = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, 3, 2]})

null_index = d['A'].isnull()

d.loc[~null_index, ['A']] = scaler.fit_transform(d.loc[~null_index, ['A']])
```

Comment: This solution is nice but insufficient if multiple columns have to be normalized (or then a loop may have to be considered)

Comment: In my case you would only want one column per MinMaxScaler object.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that sklearn now (June 2020) behaves as you (and me) desire:
np.nan is left untouched.
(mainly copy pasted from sklearn docs)

```
import sklearn
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sklearn.__version__
# '0.23.1'
data = np.array([[-1, 2, 3], [-0.5, 6,3 ], [np.nan, 18, 3 ]])
print(data)
#[[-1.   2.   3. ]
# [-0.5  6.   3. ]
# [ nan 18.   3. ]]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
data = scaler.fit_transform(data)
print(data)
#[[0.   0.   0.  ]
# [1.   0.25 0.  ]
# [ nan 1.   0.  ]]
```